# How do I build this complex database query in CakePHP 3.0?

Tags: cakephp

This is my database design, or at least the tables that are relevant to this question.

[image]

I want to build a query that returns a single page (find will be based on the `path` attribute), with the associated container, with its associated child-containers in threaded form and all of those containers should individually have their associated blocks with them (preferably in the right order sorted by the `index` column from the blocks_pages table).

Can anybody give me a clue how to wrap that all up with the query-builder? Or if that is not possible, then is it possible to do it using the new map/reduce feature, since the after-find function has been removed?

In case it helps, this will be the visualized result, if you just ignore the magenta Article-box for a moment.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$pagesTable
  ->find()
  ->where(['path' => $myPath])
  ->contain([
   'Containers.ChildContainers' => function($q) {
      return $q->formatResults(function($results) {
        return $results->map(function($container) {
            $container->nested = $container->source()
              ->find('children', ['for' => $container->id])
              ->find('threaded')
              ->contain(['Blocks']);
            return $container;
        });
      });
   },
   'Containers.ChildContainers.Blocks'
  ])
```

Comment: **edit**, I gave you the "accepted answer" check, but I took it back because there's still one thing going wrong. Right now I'm also getting blocks that are connected to a different page. You see, several pages could use the same containers, so that's why when the code gets the associated Blocks from the ChildContainers, it should also check if the page_id in the BlocksPages table matches the current page. Do you have any idea how to put in that check?

Comment: Right now I fixed the problem using [this monstrous piece of code](http://pastebin.com/4YrHr9AE). If you know a cleaner way to do it then I am all ears.

Comment: No, I don't think it can get better than that. If you think about it, you are achieving a lot with a single statement. You can break the callbacks inside into custom finders inside the other Tables or as protected functions inside the Pages Table. That will improve readability